# Angular-CLI & ThreeJS

Tags: angular, three.js, angular-cli

I have been trying to add the proper npm dependencies to add THREE to my Angular-CLI project.  With CLI changing so rapidly in the past few months, I haven't been able to find working source.

### Here are a few ideas...

- #### Piggyback with scripts

  This was my first attempt, to simply add `<script src="three.js"></script>` to the index.html file.  However I'm having trouble working with the javascript in the typescript interface.
- #### Webpack

  This was my second attempt, but I ran into several documentation problems.  Angular-cli doesn't seem to have a consistent way of using webpacks.  There are four different ways of implementing webpacks.  I wasn't able to get any working with THREE.
- #### Bundles

  This seems like a hack, and a poor/lengthy one.  It would be to add bundles to the THREE library so that it can be interpreted angular 2.

I'm still currently working on making a Angluar-CLI + THREE.js project.  If I don't see progress in the next week, I may drop angular-cli.  Any advice/sources would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 44):

As of angular-cli `1.0.0`:

1. `npm install three --save`
2. `npm install @types/three --save-dev`
3. Add a div element in AppComponent.html: `<div #rendererContainer></div>`
4. Import three.js in AppComponent.ts: `import * as THREE from 'three';`
5. Get a handle to your div element with `@ViewChild('rendererContainer') rendererContainer: ElementRef;`
6. Do the necessary setup in your constructor / lifecycle methods. Note: the `ViewChild` is not available until `ngAfterViewInit`.

Full AppComponent:

```
import {Component, ViewChild, ElementRef} from '@angular/core';
import * as THREE from 'three';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
    @ViewChild('rendererContainer') rendererContainer: ElementRef;

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    scene = null;
    camera = null;
    mesh = null;

    constructor() {
        this.scene = new THREE.Scene();

        this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000);
        this.camera.position.z = 1000;

        const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(200, 200, 200);
        const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xff0000, wireframe: true});
        this.mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

        this.scene.add(this.mesh);
    }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
        this.rendererContainer.nativeElement.appendChild(this.renderer.domElement);
        this.animate();
    }

    animate() {
        window.requestAnimationFrame(() => this.animate());
        this.mesh.rotation.x += 0.01;
        this.mesh.rotation.y += 0.02;
        this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);
    }
}
```

Full AppComponent.html:

```
<div #rendererContainer></div>
```

**If you want to use some of the additional scripts:**

You may end up wanting to use some of the additional scripts, such as loaders and controls. Most of these haven't been written as modules, but instead add functionality to the `THREE` namespace on the `window` when loaded. Because of this I ended up telling the angular-cli to just load up my scripts manually by adding the following to my `.angular-cli.json` file:

```
{
  "apps": [
    {
      "scripts": [
        "../node_modules/tween.js/src/Tween.js",
        "../node_modules/three/build/three.js",
        "../node_modules/stats.js/build/stats.min.js",
        "../vendor/VRMLLoader.js",
        "../vendor/OrbitControls.js"
      ],
      ...
```

Note that you will also need to deal with the fact that your three.js @types file does not define any types for these additional scripts. Ideally I would like to extend the existing type definitions, but for the time being I am just foregoing type hinting for three.js to get around the errors by adding `declare const THREE: any` to the top of my files that use three.js. If you find a good way to instead extend the existing definitions from `@types/three`, please report back!

**To handle resizing the window:**

While I am at it I will also mention that resizing your `window` can cause things like [raycasting](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/core/Raycaster) (which I use to decide if an object is clicked) to not work correctly anymore. To fix this just do:

```
@HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])
onWindowResize(event) {
    this.renderer.setSize(event.target.innerWidth, event.target.innerHeight)
}
```

Comment: Awesome example man, thanks. Do you have any idea how to use the STLLoader with webpack and the angular cli?

Comment: @EricScandora Added some instructions regarding the additional scripts like loaders and controls. Let me know if anything doesn't work or if you have any additional questions!

Comment: unfortunately, I can not use three.js  it can not load three : Error: (SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:3000/three

Comment: @sancelot I will not be of much assistance with your issue because all of the information in this answer is related to using the [angular-cli](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli), which uses `Webpack` (as apposed to `SystemJS`, which you appear to be using).

Comment: @mattblang I am brand new, evaluating angular capabilities. I began with quickstart tutorial and added some features to the project.  I was not aware of these systems . if you can point myself some useful links. thanks

Comment: This worked great. I got it up and running with Angular4. Isn't there a requirement to pass any rendering through Angular's Renderer2?

Comment: Probably want to stick a --save-dev on the @types install