# THREE is not defined in Angular

Tags: three.js

I am using the latest package of `three` from `npm` and would like to import it in an Angular 10 project.

```
var THREE = require("three");
var FBXLoader = require("three/examples/js/loaders/FBXLoader");
```

And the infamous error message:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: THREE is not defined
    at Object.W5wy (FBXLoader.js:18)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:79)
```

I do understand that `THREE` is not defined in the FBXLoader but how does this package exist, when it can't be imported by a regular `require` import?

Does anyone know how to fix this? Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: Related [Angular-CLI & ThreeJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40273300/angular-cli-threejs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are importing the non-module version of the FBXLoader, I think. Try (`jsm` instead of `js` in the path):

```
var FBXLoader = require("three/examples/jsm/loaders/FBXLoader");
```

This works with ES modules at least:

```
import * as THREE from "three";
import { FBXLoader } from "three/examples/jsm/loaders/FBXLoader.js";
```